# mongodb get documents with max count

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a collection storing documents in following format:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("56c48ffa6a650517eccd147b"),
"Token" : "diamond",
"sentence_id" : ObjectId("5665627c6a650522082d5209")
```

there are repeating values in field token

```
"_id" : ObjectId("56c48ffa6a650517eccd147c"),
"Token" : "diamond",
"sentence_id" : ObjectId("5665627c6a650522082d5230")
```

I need to get top ten tokens with higher count value. I need to write this query in C#. Can anyone help??

Comment: i tried in mongodb query but unable to code it in c#

Comment: Post your MongoDB query, maybe I or someone else can walk you through translating it.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilise [C#: Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/aggregation/#data-aggregation-with-c-driver) to  perform group by `Token` field and sort by the count of `Token` occurrences.

For example to do this in C#:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
                          // Group by Token, and count occurrences
                          .Group(new BsonDocument { 
                                         { "_id", "$Token" }, 
                                         { "count", new BsonDocument("$sum", 1) } })
                          // Sort by count number
                          .Sort(new BsonDocument { { "count", -1 } })
                          // Limit only top ten
                          .Limit(10);
        var results = await aggregate.ToListAsync();
        foreach (var obj in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
        }
```

See [gist: simple aggregation](https://gist.github.com/sindbach/1bdc89766df80f7eb22d0ccd8f1be60a) for the code. The code was written with .Net v4.5.2 and [mongocsharpdriver-2.2.3](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/).

Also check out [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) and it's [list of available operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) for more information. You may also be interested in [$out operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/#pipe._S_out) to store the output of the aggregation in a collection for later.

Hope that helps.